# pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate in dataframe with only numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file like this:

```
year,value
1897.386301369863,0.6
1897.3890410958904,1.1
1897.3917808219178,0.0
1897.3945205479451,8.3
1897.3972602739725,3.3
1897.4,6.7
1897.4027397260274,0.6
1897.4054794520548,2.2
1897.4082191780822,0.6
1897.4109589041095,9.4
1897.4136986301369,9.4
1897.4164383561645,31.1
```

This is the code I've written:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("[Path to file is here]", header=0, sep=",")
df1["year"] = df1["year"].astype(int)
n1 = df1.groupby("year")["value"].mean()
```

Yet I keep receiving this error message:

pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I've checked this code many times, it has worked before, but I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: This just works, Tired just now, Out of curiosity why it the `year` a decimal number ?

Comment: The year is meant to be a date throughout the year, so each date is a fraction of the year.  When I try it, i get the error message.

Comment: what is your pandas version ? Pandas by default tries to determine types unless told via `dtype` 

Ref : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: My version is 0.25.3

Comment: Is it reproducible in a different folder ? just dump the csv file and the python file to a new folder. Run it via a command prompt. No UI no venv

Comment: Tried it, and I still get the same error message.

Comment: can you run the following and add the output to the question as well 

`import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("[Path to file is here]", header=0, sep=",")
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df1.to_string())`

I suspect it is data related at this stage

Comment: year     float64
value     object
dtype: object

Comment: It then prints the entire dataframe, which is thousands of rows long

Comment: K explains it, `value` column had a value that pandas could not interpret as a float. Run the following and you will find the line number where it goes bang

`import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("./a.csv", header=0, sep=",")

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    try:
        x = float(row['value'])
    except:
        print(f'Casting Error at row: {index + 2}')
        exit(1)

df1["year"] = df1["year"].astype(int)
n1 = df1.groupby("year")["value"].mean()`

Comment: The problematic rows are the ones where I have missing data (there is no text in the values column). Is there a way to fix this, like maybe adding np.nan or something?

Comment: Try `df1["value"] = df1["value"].fillna(0)` **before** `groupby`, In your case I believe you may be having spaces. If yes, this may not work

Comment: But wouldn't replacing the missing data with 0 affect the average? Edit: and yes, there are spaces

Comment: It will, if required you can filter-out the missing data and then do the calculation. *I do not know the business impact on this* as this is not my application

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df1["year"] = df1["year"].astype(int)
df1["value"] = pd.to_numeric(df1["value"])

n1 = df1.groupby("year")["value"].mean()
```

Comment: what does pd.to_numeric do that wasn't done before?

Comment: @Felix convert none numeric to numeric

Comment: There is a slight problem, my csv has some missing data. I tried your suggestion, but i get a new error message: Unable to parse string " "

Answer (score 0):

**If replacing missing `value` data with `0` is Fine, the following will solve your issue**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv("./a.csv", header=0, sep=",")
df1["value"] = df1["value"].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df1["value"] = df1["value"].astype(float)

df1["year"] = df1["year"].astype(int)
df1["value"] = df1["value"].fillna(0)

n1 = df1.groupby("year")["value"].mean()
print(n1)
```

**If you want to omit missing data use the following**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv("./a.csv", header=0, sep=",")
df1["value"] = df1["value"].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df1 = df1[~df1["value"].isnull()]

df1["value"] = df1["value"].astype(float)
df1["year"] = df1["year"].astype(int)
df1["value"] = df1["value"].fillna(0)

n1 = df1.groupby("year")["value"].mean()
print(n1)
```